How to combine 2 get requests?
I'm making an application and in the header is a searchbar where you can write something in and that searches and gives the results.
Now on the page with the results I have another form where you can filter on type (player or team). The problem is, that if I search and then apply the filter, the keywoard from the search query is gone... How can that be shown in the searchbar and also be saved to use if the page is reloaded with a filter?
This is in the header the searchbar
 <form class="d-none d-lg-flex" role="search" th:action="@{/search}" method="get">
                    <label for="keyword"></label>
                    <input class="form-control me-2" name="keyword" id="keyword" type="text"
                           placeholder="search team or player">
                    <input type="submit" value="search" class="btn">
                </form>

This is the form in the search page
  <form th:action="@{/search}" method="get">
            <p>Filters</p>
            <div>
                <h3>Type</h3>
                <label for="all">all</label>
                <input type="radio" id="all" name="type" value="all"/>
                <label for="team">team</label>
                <input type="radio" id="team" name="type" value="team"/>
                <label for="player">player</label>
                <input type="radio" id="player" name="type" value="player"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="search">
            </div>
        </form>

And this is the search Controller
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String search(Model model,
                         @RequestParam(required = false) String keyword,
                         @RequestParam(required = false) String type) {


        List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        teams = teamRepository.findAllByKeyword(keyword);
        players = playerRepository.findAllByKeyword(keyword);

        if (type == null || type.isEmpty() || type.equals("all")) {
            model.addAttribute("teams", teams);
            model.addAttribute("players", players);
            model.addAttribute("totalPlayers", players.size());
            model.addAttribute("totalTeams", teams.size());
        } else if (type.equals("team")) {
            model.addAttribute("teams", teams);
            model.addAttribute("totalTeams", teams.size());
        } else if (type.equals("player")) {
            model.addAttribute("players", players);
            model.addAttribute("totalPlayers", players.size());
        }

        logoService.addLogos(model);

        return "search";
    }

So the problem is that the first time if I search all the results are shown but then when filter applied nothing is shown probably because the keyword isn't there anymore.

At the very least, could you set a hidden form field in the page you produce for the search results, that contains the search keyword?

@ndc85430 brilliant idea!

You can have one form for search field and filter (even outside the form tag):
<!-- Add ID to your form -->
<form id="myform" class="d-none d-lg-flex" role="search" th:action="@{/search}" method="get">
    <label for="keyword"></label>
    <input class="form-control me-2" name="keyword" id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="search team or player" th:value="${previousKeywordValue}">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="btn">
</form>

...

<!-- Connect your inputs OUTSIDE of the form-tag to your form =) -->
<p>Filters</p>
<div>
  <h3>Type</h3>
  <label for="all">all</label>
  <input type="radio" id="all" name="type" value="all" form="myform" th:checked="${previousTypeValue == 'all'}"/>
  
  <label for="team">team</label>
  <input type="radio" id="team" name="type" value="team" form="myform" th:checked="${previousTypeValue == 'team'}"/>
  
  <label for="player">player</label>
  <input type="radio" id="player" name="type" value="player" form="myform" th:checked="${previousTypeValue == 'player'}"/>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="search" form="myform">
</div>


In this case you can call submit from one of two submit buttons, but in any case you will send all your form with keyword and filter values.
After controller processing you can add previous keyword and filter attributes to the model and install them to fields:
@GetMapping("/search")
public String search(Model model,
                     @RequestParam(required = false) String keyword,
                     @RequestParam(required = false) String type) {
    ...
     model.addAttribute("previousKeywordValue", keyword);
     model.addAttribute("previousTypeValue", type);
    ...

    return "search";
}

Between any form confirmations you will have saved previous keyword and filter values.
